# Crop image into pieces and then join, is that possible using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I have several samples from color images that I should turn into binary. I obtained the best results by using **adaptive thresholding**.

The numbers are very good, well-defined, but is noisy around and these "vertical lines" that separate each number ends up being read as a number 1 for OCR tool, for example.

Then I noticed that around the numbers the image is clean. I thought if I could cut out only the numbers (before or after making the picture black and white?) and then "paste" these numbers tp a white background.

I tried applying *erosion* and *dilation*, but still many leftover "points". If I could do what I'm thinking (above), it will reduce the erosion/dilation and increase the "cleaning" around the number before the cut, I don't know.

Is that possible? Did I make any sense? If yes, how could I do this using OpenCV? Any suggestions?

Some images that I'm using:

[image: rgb image1]

[image: image1 after adaptive threshold]

[image: rgb image2]

[image: image2 after adaptive threshold]

**Note:** The images above have not gone through the processes of erosion and / or dilation, adaptive thresholding only.

---

Update:

@Mahm00d, I tried what you said with the first image and I got the image below, which is very good, but the problem with the reflection in the first two numbers continues. Is there any way to fix this? I applied the adaptive threshold but the image remains quite noise.

GaussianBlur + Treshold with OTSU flag:
[image: gaussian + otsu]

GaussianBlur + Adaptive Threshold:
[image: gaussian + adaptive]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often good to first use some **denoising** technique, like *Gaussian/Median blur* before going through thresholding and morphology:

(Code in Java)

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(inputMat, gMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
// Gaussian blur : 21x21 window, sigma = 50.0 (select these accordignly)
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(gMat, gMat, new Size(21.0, 21.0), 50.0);
// Otsu thresholding (or any other thresholding techinique...)
Imgproc.threshold(gMat, gMat, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU | Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
```

Your output:

[image]

Above code output:

[image]

---

**Update:**

These problems often need some playing with parameter values to get a good result and achieve optimal values. In the case of the second image, here is the code I used (adaptive threshold) to get a better result:

```
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(inImg, inImg, new Size(21.0, 21.0), 50.0);
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(inImg, inImg, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 111, -20);
```

Result:

[image]

Of course it's not perfect, but at least the reflection is removed. Also, morphological processes can help yield better results.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to apply dilation and erosion and find all contours that are smaller than X-pixels and fill them with white color:

```
int main()
{
    // Load the image as a Grayscale
    Mat image = imread("image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    // Threshold the image
    image = image > 120;
    // Create bigger image with image width and height + 10 pixels
    Mat image_big = Mat::zeros( image.size().height + 10, image.size().width + 10, CV_8UC1 );
    // Set bigger image to be all white
    image_big.setTo(255);

    Mat image_big_copy;

    // This may vary, you must find it for yourself
    // Dilate image 4 times and erode once
    dilate(image, image, Mat(), Point(-1,-1), 4);
    erode(image, image, Mat(), Point(-1,-1));

    // Copy image in the center of bigger image so you left 5px around image blank/white
    // Create a new ROI that points to center of the bigger image
    Mat image_big_roi = image_big( Rect(Point(5, 5), Size(image.size())) );
    // Copy image to the bigger image ROI
    addWeighted(image_big_roi, 0., image, 1., 0., image_big_roi);

    // Create a data copy of image_big
    image_big.copyTo(image_big_copy);

    // Find all contours in a given image and store them in contours
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    findContours(image_big_copy, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        // This is your condition to filter out unwanted contours etc.
        // For every contour if its area is bigger/smaller than the sum of pixels
        if ( fabs(contourArea(Mat(contours[i]))) < 800 )
        {
            // Fill a contour with white color
            drawContours(image_big, contours, i, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);
        }
    }

    imshow("Image original", image);
    imshow("Image edited", image_big);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Original image:

[image]

After:

[image]